# How to disable access to a file inside a directory nginx

Tags: nginx

Hello I'm trying to prevent access to the file /wp-admin/load-scripts.php in the nginx config
I'm currently working with

```
 location ~ \/wp-admin\/load-(scripts|styles).php {
        deny all;
        }
```

and it's still allowing access to the file

Comment: Does `location ~ /wp-admin/load-(scripts|styles)\.php { deny all; }` work?

Comment: Nope, I've tried it and can confirm it dose not work :/

Comment: Just for reference this is what I'm trying to prevent https://wpcerber.com/how-to-protect-wordpress-against-cve-2018-6389/

Comment: I usually go the other way and `allow` what I need and `deny all`, but this requires testing all of the installed configured templates and plugins. In one config I do have specific location blocked, but for that I have `\.php$`. I can't remember now why I used the `$`.

Comment: Right but i don't need /load-scripts.php

Comment: Does `location ~ /wp-admin/load-(scripts|styles)\.php$ {  return 404;  }` work?

Comment: Please post the `server` block.

Comment: i successfully got the configuration working but unfortunately the exploit still persists.

Comment: Thank you Paul and Annahri for the help